# Elasticsearch date range must not be between multiple date_begin, date_end

Tags: elasticsearch

I have `check_in` and `check_out` "d-m-Y" search fields in my application. These searches available members between these dates.
On the other hand, members can edit their calendars and can put any date ranges to calendar marked as not available.
For example : Alice's calendar.
This is just related index in elastic.

Note : There is no multiple search filters, I just write them to show several cases. For this searches, Alice mustn't be found by elastic search.

```
Example Searches:
 check_in  "04-12-2015"
 check_out "07-12-2015"

 check_in  "08-12-2015"
 check_out "11-12-2015"

 check_in  "09-12-2015"
 check_out "15-12-2015"

 check_in  "05-12-2015"
 check_out "11-12-2015"


"Alice's Not available Calendar" : [
    {
        "date_begin" : "05-12-2015",
        "date_end'   : '09-12-2015"
    },
    {
        "date_begin" : "01-01-2016",
        "date_end'   : '07-02-2016"
    },
    {
        "date_begin" : "09-04-2016",
        "date_end'   : '11-04-2016"
    },
    {
        "date_begin" : "17-04-2016",
        "date_end'   : '21-04-2016"
    }
]
```

I should check these assertions:

```
{check_in} lte {date_begin} and
{check_out} lte {date_end}

check_in
    date_begin
check_out
    date_end


{check_in} gte {date_begin} and
{check_out} lte {date_end}    

    date_begin
check_in
check_out
    date_end



{check_in} lte {date_begin} and
{check_out} gte {date_end}    

check_in
    date_begin
    date_end
check_out



{check_in} gte {date_begin} and
{check_out} gte {date_end}

    date_begin
check_in
    date_end
check_out
```

For these information how should I send my query to filter in desired way ? I couldn't imagine how should be in proper way.

Something like this, but how could I write correct syntax.

```
{
"bool" : {
    "must_not" : {
        "range" : {
            "date_begin" : { "lte" : "{check_in}" }
        }
    },
    <---- AND ----->
    "must_not" : {
        "range" : {
            "date_end" : { "lte" : "{check_out}" }
        }
    },
    <---- OR ----->
    "must_not" : {
        "range" : {
            "date_begin" : { "gte" : "{check_in}" }
        }
    },
    <---- AND ----->
    "must_not" : {
        "range" : {
            "date_end" : { "lte" : "{check_out}" }
        }
    },
    <---- OR ----->
    "must_not" : {
        "range" : {
            "date_begin" : { "lte" : "{check_in}" }
        }
    },
    <---- AND ----->
    "must_not" : {
        "range" : {
            "date_end" : { "gte" : "{check_out}" }
        }
    },
    <---- OR ----->
    "must_not" : {
        "range" : {
            "date_begin" : { "gte" : "{check_in}" }
        }
    },
    <---- AND ----->
    "must_not" : {
        "range" : {
            "date_end" : { "gte" : "{check_out}" }
        }
    },
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the search should return members with following conditions.

1)`date_begin` should be greater that both `check_in` and `check_out`

**OR**

2)`date_end` should be less that both `check_in` and `check_out`

Lets say user enters *2014-02-19* as `check_in` date and *2014-02-20* as `check_out` date then I think following query will satisfy all your requirements

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "date_begin": {
                    "gt": "2014-02-19"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "date_begin": {
                    "gt": "2014-02-20"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "date_end": {
                    "lt": "2014-02-19"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "date_end": {
                    "lt": "2014-02-20"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This will give you all available members.

Comment: Thanks @ChintanShah25 for the reply, not exactly It represent date_end

    check_in

    check_out

date_begin  only this situation. But it gave me and idea and I find the answer.

Comment: {
  "must_not": [
    {
      "range": {
        "assertion.calendars.dateBegin": {
          "gte": "2015-09-04",
          "lte": "2015-09-06"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "range": {
        "assertion.calendars.dateEnd": {
          "gte": "2015-09-04",
          "lte": "2015-09-06"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}   @ChintanShah25 This makes query valid.

Comment: @FZE can you share your final query please? I want to do something similar.